# Python. Trying to write a function called one_frame. Does not seem to work. Help would be greatly appreciated

Tags: python-3.x

As of right now, this is my code:

```
def get_orf(DNA):

    codon = ''
    if(DNA[0:3] == 'ATG'):
        codon = DNA[0:3]
        for x in range(3,len(DNA)+1,3):
            if DNA[x:x+3] == "TAG"  or DNA[x:x+3] == "TAA" or DNA[x:x+3] == "TGA":
                return codon
            else: codon = codon + DNA[x:x+3] 

    if codon[-3:] in ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]:
        return codon
    else: return 'No ORF'  

def one_frame(DNA):

    x = 0
    ORFlist = []

    while x < len(DNA):
        codon = DNA[x:]
        if DNA.startswith('ATG'):
            get_orf(DNA[x:])
            if codon:
                ORFlist.append(codon)
            x += len(codon)
    return(ORFlist)
```

get_orf function works fine but my one_frame function doesn't work.
The one_frame function is supposed to take a DNA string as input. It searches that
string from left to right in multiples of three nucleotides–that is, in a single reading frame. When
it hits a start codon “ATG" it calls get_orf on the slice of the string beginning at that start codon
(until the end) to get back an ORF. That ORF is added to a list of ORFs and then the function skips
ahead in the DNA string to the point right after the ORF that we just found and starts looking for
the next ORF. This is repeated until we’ve traversed the entire DNA string.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Show us some samples of your expected output and how it differs from the actual result.

Comment: Here are some examples of expected outputs:

>>> one_frame("AATGCCATGTGAATGCCCTAA")
[‘ATG’, ‘ATGCCC’]

>>> one_frame("ATGCCCATGGGGAAATTTTGACCC")
[‘ATGCCCATGGGGAAATTT’]

But I can't seem to even run the function is the main problem.

Comment: My answer gives the correct output for those two examples. Is there any other problem with it?

Comment: Every time I run the function, the console does not print anything at all. I am hitting the run button with my code. Yet, I am still getting no output.

Comment: Are you printing the output? Try `print(one_frame("AATGCCATGTGAATGCCCTAA"))`

Comment: The function is working perfectly now. Thank you guys for all the help. I learned a thing or two from the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few obvious problems but not sure exactly what you want so hope this helps. Firstly your `for` loop in `one_frame` will never end unless DNA starts with 'ATG'. I think you want to check `codon.startswith` instead of `DNA.startswith`. You also need to do the `x+=` command outside of the if statement, or it will never be updated when you don't hit 'ATG' and so your loop will continue forever. You're also not using the value of `get_orf` at all.

I think this will do the trick,

```
def one_frame(DNA):

    x = 0
    ORFlist = []

    while x < len(DNA):
        codon = DNA[x:]
        # Check codon instead of DNA
        if codon.startswith('ATG'):
            # Record the return value of get_orf
            orf_return_value = get_orf(DNA[x:])

            if orf_return_value:

                ORFlist.append(orf_return_value)

            x += len(orf_return_value)
        # Increment by 3 if we don't hit ATG
        else:
            x += 3

    return(ORFlist)
```